# Evaluate functions in Python

Tags: python, function, eval

I have to do the following :

> A function eval_f(f, xs) which takes a function f = f(x) and a list xs of values that should be used as arguments for f. The function eval_f should apply the function f subsequently to every value x in xs, and return a list fs of function values. I.e. for an input argument xs=[x0, x1, x2,..., xn] the function eval_f(f, xs) should return [f(x0), f(x1), f(x2), ..., f(xn)].

```
import math


def eval_f(f, xs):

    x = []
    f = f(x)
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        f.append(f(x[i]))
    return f
```

eval_f(math.sqrt, [1, 2, 4, 9])
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    eval_f(math.sqrt, [1, 2, 4, 9])

File "C:/Users/Idoia/untitled2.py", line 6, in eval_f
    f = f(x)

TypeError: a float is required

Comment: And? What happens?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It shows an error saying that it needs a float

Comment: Please [edit] with the full error and traceback

Comment: I think you want `x.append`, anyway. `f` is a function, not a list

Comment: You also want to return `x`, and apply `f` on `xs[i]` rather than `x[i]`. Also what's with `f = f(x)`?

Comment: Are you basically being asked to re-write Python's builtin `map`?

Comment: Why even write this ``eval_f`` function? It exists already as a builtin and is called ``map``

Answer (score 2):

> for an input argument xs=[x0, x1, x2,..., xn] the function eval_f(f, xs) should return [f(x0), f(x1), f(x2), ..., f(xn)].

You want to `map` a function `f` over a list

If using Python3,

```
def eval_f(f, xs):
    return list(map(f, xs))
```

You can remove the `list()` for python2

Answer (score 1):

```
def test(x):
  return x*2

def eval_f(f, xs):
    ans = []
    for x in xs:
        ans.append(f(x))
    return ans

print(eval_f(test,[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Prints out:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: I understand that this is probably some sort of homework where they want a detailed solution, but in python you could simply do `map(f, list)` to replace the loop.

Comment: That's true. More "Pythonic"

Comment: Aren't people aware of list comprehensions? ``return [f(x) for x in xs]`` instead of the for loop

Comment: I just copied @I.R's code and made edits to it... Didn't give it much thoughts...